# Is it possible to call toString (custom print) when using comma in console.log

Tags: javascript

I am experimenting with creating custom print for objects. I notice that using `+` in console.log uses the object's `toString`. The default `toString` returns `[object Object]`. I also notice that using `,` simply prints all the properties and their values. Is it possible that my custom print (toString) gets called when using comma in console.log?

```
var a = {
    someAProperty: 1,
    toString: function() {
    return "the custom print is " + this.someAProperty;
  }
}

var b = {
    someBProperty: 2
}

class C {
    constructor(someCProperty){
        this.someCProperty=someCProperty;
    };
}

C.prototype.toString = function customPrint(){
    return "someCProperty is "+this.someCProperty;
}

class D {
    constructor(someDProperty){
        this.someDProperty=someDProperty;
    };
}

function printObject(){
    console.log("\nusing , \n a:( object with toString property)",a,"\nb (object without toString):",b,"\nc (class with toString):",new C(1),"\nd (class without toString) ", new D(4));
    console.log("\nusing + \n a:( object with toString property)"+a+"\nb (object without toString):"+b+"\nc (class with toString):"+new C(1)+"\nd (class without toString) "+ new D(4));
}

printObject()
```

To run the above code, I used `node.js`

```
node print.js

using ,
 a:( object with toString property) { someAProperty: 1, toString: [Function: toString] }
b (object without toString): { someBProperty: 2 }
c (class with toString): C { someCProperty: 1 }
d (class without toString)  D { someDProperty: 4 }

using +
 a:( object with toString property)the custom print is 1
b (object without toString):[object Object]
c (class with toString):someCProperty is 1
d (class without toString) [object Object]
```

Could I get the following output when I use comma in `console.log`? i.e. `console.log("\nusing , \n a:( object with toString property)",a,"\nb (object without toString):",b,"\nc (class with toString):",new C(1),"\nd (class without toString) ", new D(4));`

```
a:( object with toString property)the custom print is 1
    b (object without toString):[object Object]
    c (class with toString):someCProperty is 1
    d (class without toString) [object Object]
```

Comment: `console.log` is not standardized, i.e. different browsers might implement different heuristics to serialize values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`console.log` accepts a variable number of parameters and outputs them. When you use `+` in your example, you're doing `"some string" + object` and so the `+` ends up being string concatenation (nothing to do with `console.log`) and the resulting string is passed into `console.log` as a single argument. When you use the comma, you're passing two distinct arguments to `console.log` and it handles each of them in its own way.

There's nothing that you can include on your object that will cause its `toString` to be called unless you force it to be (for instance, by using `+` or `String(yourObject)`), but **some** consoles (such as the one in Node.js) will use a function called `inspect` if it's on your object:

```
const util = require('util');

var obj = {
  answer: 42
};
console.log("Without inspect", obj);
obj[util.inspect.custom] = function() {
    return "The answer is " + this.answer;
};
console.log("With inspect", obj);
```

Otherwise, just ensure you force to string when calling `console.log` (perhaps by using a wrapper function instead of calling it directly).

Answer (score 0):

Call `.toString()` explicitly:

```
console.log("\nusing , \n a:( object with toString property)", a.toString(),
    "\nb (object without toString):", b.toString(),
    "\nc (class with toString):", (new C(1)).toString(),
    "\nd (class without toString) ", (new D(4)).toString());
```